# Print html before downloading zip file

Tags: php, symfony, buffer, flush

Hello fellow coders !

I am looking for a solution to show a html page while my php code prepares a .zip which is then downloaded. The reason is because sometimes the zips are quite bigger and take time to make.

The HTML page would be a basic "Please wait while your .zip files is being prepared". 
The PHP side used is Symfony. So I come into my getInboxExportAction function by calling https://myapi.com/orders/orderid/inbox/export.

The download function (makeExportDownloadRequestResponse) works fine. But if I add a flush after making my $response, the .zip is printed to the html, instead of being downloaded...

```
public function getInboxExportAction(Request $request, $orderId)
{

    $response = new Response($this->twig->render('base.html.twig',
            ['content' => '
            <h1>Download</h1>
            <p>Your zip is being prepared for download, please wait...</p>
        ']));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    //Here I would like to echo + flush my html. 
    //Then stop the flush and continue my code
    $receivedOrder = $this->fetchRequestedReceivedOrder($orderId);
    if (!$receivedOrder instanceof ReceivedOrder) {
        return $receivedOrder;
    }

    if (!$receivedOrder->getSentorder()) {
        $this->makeErrorResponse('Sent order was not found', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return $this->makeExportDownloadRequestResponse($receivedOrder->getSentorder(), $request->get('format'));

}
```

I am also very open to any other ideas anyone would have to fix this issue :)

Thanks,

Edit : My  $this->makeExportDownloadRequestResponse() function returns a response, not a path. We unlink the file on the server for storage reasons.

```
 $content = file_get_contents($zipTmpFile);
 unlink($zipTmpFile);
 $response = new Response($content);
 $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'myFile_' . date('Y_m_d_h_i_s') . '.zip');
 $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);
 return $response;
```

Second edit : I understand that what I'm trying to do (change the content-type within one call) I generally frowned upon. I'm currently trying to think of a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your `getInboxExportAction`, just return a response with your text.

Then, in this response, add a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=xxx">` tag to redirect the user to another action that will generate the zip file.

You can also handle this redirection with javascript.

Note that you can use a `StreamedResponse` to handle the zip download: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response

Comment: Thanks for the solution, which sounds quite nifty. Although I couldn't use it in my project, I will keep this for another time.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is you set `$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');`, the browser will not download the .zip file.

If your `makeExportDownloadRequestResponse` method can return the absolute .zip file path (or you can calculate it), you can try:

```
public function getInboxExportAction(Request $request, $orderId)
{

    $response = new Response($this->twig->render('base.html.twig',
            ['content' => '
            <h1>Download</h1>
            <p>Your zip is being prepared for download, please wait...</p>
        ']));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    //Here I would like to echo + flush my html. 
    //Then stop the flush and continue my code
    $receivedOrder = $this->fetchRequestedReceivedOrder($orderId);
    if (!$receivedOrder instanceof ReceivedOrder) {
        return $receivedOrder;
    }

    if (!$receivedOrder->getSentorder()) {
        $this->makeErrorResponse('Sent order was not found', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // prepare the to be downloaded zip file
    // then, do sth to get the .zip file path
    $zipFilePath = $this->makeExportDownloadRequestResponse($receivedOrder->getSentorder(), $request->get('format'));        

    // re-set header
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=whateverName.zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFilePath));
    readfile($zipFilePath);
}
```

It will let browser downloads the zip file.

Finally, If your function is work as an API, and you need a frontend JS to execute it, try with `Blob` class on JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a StreamedResponse to get it rid of this issue. About the fact that the whole .wip file content being displayed because of the flush, try to call **ob_flush** before

Comment: I couldn't change the content-type in the StreamedResponse, but thanks for the submission :)